# What is the best way of getting the values that will be typed at dynamically generated inputs

Tags: javascript

I've got a form that creates inputs dynamically.

An example of it would be something like this:

```
<form>
    <input name="item[0][name]">
    <input name="item[1][name]">
</form>
```

The `0` and `1` being the id of the item.

Note that the `0` and `1` could be `15` and `49`, or even `520`, `854` and `2`.

**There's no order neither ordination and, there is also no limit for being only two items.**

The question is:

"What is the best way of getting the values that will be typed at those inputs, before sending them to the backend?"

The only way I can think of is adding ids when generating the form, but that doesn't seem elegant at all.

If you cant figure a better way, that would be lovely =)

Comment: elements array, basic selector, getElementsByTagName, a class, etc.? Tones of ways to select them

Comment: @epascarello How would you use a basic selector, if you don't know how many inputs would be generated? The same for ByTagName, their name can change. Using a class would be less bad than id, but still think could be done better.

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski yeah, but I have to test'em first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `document.querySelectorAll()` and Attribute Selector

```js
function submit() {
  let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[name*=item]');
  let values = Array.from(inputs).map(({value})=>value);
  console.log(values);
}
```

```html
<form>
    <input name="item[0][name]">
    <input name="item[1][name]">
</form>

<button onclick="submit()">Sumbit</button>
```

Comment: really good! You could select the inputs by their name tag, that they already have. Really enjoyed it!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```js
function submit() {
  let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');
  let values = [...inputs].map(x=>x.value);
  console.log(values);
}
```

```html
<form>
    <input name="item[0][name]">
    <input name="item[1][name]">
</form>

<button onclick="submit()">Send</button>
```

Comment: @Rayon the best will be use class like `myInputs` but OP not use it and also not mention about any restriction about inputs selectors

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski using classes is fine, but I was thinking about using the name tag instead. Avoiding adding classes/ids seems more elegant.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [HTMLFormElement.elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/elements) property.

```js
const formInputs = document.getElementById('a-form').elements
const dataObject = {}

for (let i = 0; i < formInputs.length; i++) {
  dataObject[formInputs[i].name] = formInputs[i].value
}

console.log(dataObject)
```

```html
<form id="a-form">
  <input type="text" name="item[0][name]" />
  <input type="text" name="item[1][name]" />
  <input type="text" name="item[2][name]" />
</form>
```

Comment: Interesting approach, if I were to use id, that would make me add only a single id. Nice one! =)

Answer (score 0):

Set a specific **data attribute** (for instance data-my-input) on them, then use querySelectorAll(‘input[data-my-input]’) to get them all and send them to your backend.